# Delete with multiple where on different rows for same id - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure that define the relationship between posts and their categories.

```
Post_id | Category_id
---------------------
1       | A
1       | B
1       | C
2       | A
2       | B
2       | C
2       | D
```

So i want to search the post that have two given categories (For example A and B)
and then delete the row A.
So the result would be:

```
Post_id | Category_id
---------------------
1       | B
1       | C
2       | B
2       | C
2       | D
```

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete t1 
from yourtable t1
join (
    -- This sub query will retrieve records that have both A and B for each `Post_id`
    select Post_id
    from yourtable
    where Category_id in ('A', 'B')
    group by Post_id
    having count(distinct Category_id) = 2
) t2
-- Then join this sub query on your table.
on t1.Post_id = t2.Post_id
where t1.Category_id = 'A'
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ebc02/1)

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly. Btw what does t1 and t2 mean?

Comment: @Fosfor t1 and t2 are just alias for a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the posts by doing:

```
select post_id
from post_categories
where category_id in ('A', 'B')
group by post_id
having count(distinct category_id) = 2;
```

You can then delete them with a `join`:

```
delete pc
    from post_categories pc join
         (select post_id
          from post_categories
          where category_id in ('A', 'B')
          group by post_id
          having count(distinct category_id) = 2
         ) todelete
         on pc.post_id = todelete.post_id
    where pc.category_id = 'A';
```